# How to get data from button attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are several buttons (they creates dynamically)

```
<button class="common" id="1.1" status="sale" oncontextmenu="rightButton('1.1'); return false" onclick="addOptions('1.1')" number="1">1</button>
```

I need to get attributes (class, id, status, number) and insert them into object array. Then input to database.

```
function saveScheme()
{
  var table = document.getElementById('schemeTable');
  var elements = table.getElementsByTagName('button');
  var arrayIdButtons = {};
  for(var i = 0; i<elements.length; i++)
  {
    arrayIdButtons[i] = {};
    for(var j = 0; j<4; j++)
    {
      arrayIdButtons[i]["coord"] = elements.item([i]).id; 
      arrayIdButtons[i]["status"] = elements.item([i]).status; 
      arrayIdButtons[i]["type"] = elements.item([i]).class;
      arrayIdButtons[i]["number"] = elements.item([i]).number;
    }
  }
  console.log(arrayIdButtons);
  var data='data=' + JSON.stringify(arrayIdButtons,"", 2);
  $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "handler.php",
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data)
            }
        });
}
```

result of this code(`console.log(arrayIdButtons);`):

[image]

Comment: It's not a good idea to use `.` in IDs. When you write CSS selectors, `.` is used to indicate a class name, so you'll need to escape it.

Comment: What is the `for (var j` loop for? You're not using `j` for anything. And `elements.item([i])` should be `elements[i]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using jQuery, you can access the attributes of an element using `.attr()`. For example:

```
$('.common').attr('number');
```

Or, without jQuery,

```
elements[i].getAttribute('number');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use HTML5 API `data`

```
<button class="common" id="1.1" data-status="sale"  oncontextmenu="rightButton('1.1'); .....</button>
```

So,

```
elements.item([i]).data('status'); //if jquery enabled
```

Comment: This only works for `data-` attributes. It won't work for the non-standard `number` attribute.

Comment: @StephenThomas The point is not to use non-standard attributes in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this html. then,

```
<button class="common" data-id="1.1" data-status="sale" data-number="1">1</button>
```

If DOM is not loaded, then you can get this by

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".common").on("click",function(){
   var data_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
   var data_status = $(this).attr('data-status');
   var data_number = $(this).attr('data-number');
   console.log(data_id);
   console.log(data_id);
   console.log(data_id);
 });
});
```

And if DOM is already loaded you can get them by

```
$(document).on("click",".common",function(){
   var data_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
   var data_status = $(this).attr('data-status');
   var data_number = $(this).attr('data-number');
   console.log(data_id);
   console.log(data_id);
   console.log(data_id);
});
```

Then you can push this is an array. Note - this will give you the attributes of only the button was clicked